# trying to convert the string to double

Tags: c#, string, datatable, double

I have two  values  coming from database i need to convert these values into double i have done like this 
i ahve just mentioned like this just as local variables

```
            string val;
            string dpayment;
```

and i am taking the values from database by the following query

```
  if (dt != null)
  {
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {


        dpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]).ToString("0.00");

     val= Convert.ToInt32( dt.Rows[3]["value"]).ToString();       
    }
  }
```

i am using these values and doing the operation like this

```
                 double eqvperiod = Convert.ToDouble(val / dpayment).ToString();
```

but it was giving error

operator '/' cannot be used as a operands of type string and string.

any one can help on this

my final result is i want to convert the values coming from databases to double and i have to do the operations on this values

Comment: why are you storing the values that come out of your DB as strings? when you convert to int or double, why are you calling toString() on that? and if you want eqvperiod to be a double, why are you calling toString() on the division result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `double` before dividing:

```
double eqvperiod = Convert.ToDouble(val) / Convert.ToDouble(dpayment);
```

And actually, you don't need to `Convert()` then `ToString()` then `Convert()` a second time:

```
int val = 0;
double dpayment = 0.0;

if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     dpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]);

     val= Convert.ToInt32( dt.Rows[3]["value"]);       
}

double eqvperiod = val / dpayment;
```

Comment: i got the error like this " use of unassigned local varaible"                         at  double eqvperiod = val / dpayment;

Comment: cant i use database values out of this function  if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     dpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]);

     val= Convert.ToInt32( dt.Rows[3]["value"]);       
}

Comment: I've updated the answer to initialize `val` and `dpayment` which should fix that error. I'm not sure what you mean by "use database values".

Answer (score 2):

Why have you declared val and dpayment as strings?  If you want them to be numeric types then change the variable declaration and remove the ToString, i.e.

```
int val;
double dpayment;

dpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]);
val= Convert.ToInt32( dt.Rows[3]["value"]);
```

Comment: i got the error like this " use of unassigned local varaible" at double eqvperiod = val / dpayment;

Comment: Initialise the values to 0 when you declare them, i.e. int val = 0;

Comment: Initialise the values to 0 when you declare them, i.e.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double eqvperiod = (Convert.ToDouble(val) / Convert.ToDouble(dpayment));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
double eqvperiod = 0.00;

if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    eqvperiod = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]) /
                  Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[3]["value"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `double.Parse("0.010")`

this also works for int, short, decimal, and probably any other numeric types